# How to capture word containing specific word but not ending with it

Tags: regex

Right now my regex is `.+PT` but now I need to add criteria where the string does not end with that word.

Test strings would be:

of PT XYZ <- should match

XYZ PT <- should not match

adding more test string:
XYZ PT PT <- should not match

Comment: Why not `.*PT.+`? [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4wxjti/1)

Comment: @esqew because that would match XYZ PT PT, and eventhough the possibility is small for that kind of case, I'd prefer another solution if possible

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ngDqm0/1